# That's not how he really sounds like

Tags: sentence-construction

> That's not how he really **sound** like.

Or

> That's not how he really **sounds** like.

Which one is correct? And why?

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

Either:

- That's not how he really sounds.

or:

- That's not what he really sounds like.

"How he sounds like" just sounds wrong to me.

Comment: That's because it _is_ wrong.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, but I'm unable to say exactly *why* it's wrong ... :-)

Comment: _How_ describes the manner in which something is done. _What_ does not, so it needs the additional _like_ to acquire that meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both the sentences are incorrect. But if the query is regarding the usage of verb:

When you are referring to he/she/it/similar singular form, you have to use the s form of the verb. So in your case, it has to be:

> That's not how he really sounds.

But when you are referring to I/we/they/similar plural form(I is an exception), you have to use "sound".

> That's not how they really sound.